# converting a 3d list to a numpy array inserts an undesired tuple

Tags: python, json, numpy

I'm trying to load quite a large amount of data from a json file, it is supposed to be a 3d array say it is `[[[1,2],[3,4]],[[5,6],[7,8]]]`, when I load 10 instances of the 2nd dimension with the following code:

```py
with open(data_path, "r") as fp:
    data1 = ijson.items(fp, 'mfcc.item')
    d1 = (o for index, o  in zip(range(10), data1))
    d1 = list(d1)
        
with open(data_path, "r") as fp:   
    data2 = ijson.items(fp, 'labels.item')
    d2 = (i for index2, i  in zip(range(10), data2))
    d2 = list(d2)

X = np.array(d1)
y = np.array(d2)
```

it works fine, but when I try to increase the range to more than 10, it messes up the X shape and it becomes 1 dimension
I traced the output of X and found out that when the range is more than 10 it inserts a tuple in the 2nd dimension like `[([[1,2],[3,4]],[[5,6],[7,8]])]`.

What could be the solution to this?

Comment: It would be good to provide the json files (since they seem to be small) for sake of reproducibility.

Comment: @JérômeRichard that would be quite hard as the file is more than 1 GB in size

Comment: my guess is that lists or sublists differ in length, and it can no longer make a multidimensional numeric array. Instead it is 1d object dtype.  Newer numpy versions  warn about this.

Comment: Compare `data1[9]` and `data1[10]`.